# Where has the 'Open / Open All Users' option gone from the Windows 7 Start button?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

Prior to Windows 7 I used to gain access to the Start button folders by right clicking on the Start button and choosing 'Open' or 'Open All Users' from the popup menu. The popup menu in Windows 7 does not have these options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click on the Start button
2. Right-click on the 'All Programs' entry

Comment: Please don't tell me you didn't ask this question explicitly to answer it yourself.

Comment: I thinks it's quite acceptable to answer your own questions even if you're posting the question when you already know the answer. It's a good way to get useful information out there (I was trying to find the answer to this myself). Also see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/stack-overflow-etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Comment: Yes, I deliberately asked and answered my own question because I found the answer as a side-effect of another question topic, and I figured this question/answer format would be helpful to the next person who asks. I did pause to consider for a moment before doing it, but this concept has been discussed on the podcast and approved.